# Why INSERT IGNORE increments the auto_increment primary key?

Tags: mysql

I wrote a java program that accesses a MySQL innodb database.

Whenever an INSERT IGNORE statement encounters a duplicate entry the Auto Increment primary key is incremented.

Is this behaviour the expected? I think it shouldn't happen with IGNORE. That means that IGNORE actually incurs an extra overhead for writing the new primary key value.

The table is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rowname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `rowname` (`rowname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thank you!

Comment: To add to @eugene answer - you should not rely on the workaround provided at that article. And you shouldn't also rely on sequentiality or non-sequentiality of auto increment primary keys whatever database or technology you use. If you need something really deterministic - make your own, predictable model.

Comment: You're right I should not rely on sequential auto increment but I didn't want that behaviour because I suspect it would incur higher latency.

Comment: I believe insert ignore first does an insert and if that somehow fails does a delete right afterwards, thereby increasing your autoincrement.

Comment: I don't think it will add any latency. And I don't think it really does any delete as @Johan said. Just it doesn't show an error in case there was one when inserting.

Comment: I may run some measurements to see whether it incurs overhead. I suspect that changing the key value will have some extra delay in cases of mass INSERTs.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This has been the default behaviour since MySQL 5.1.22.

You can set the configuration variable [`innodb_autoinc_lock_mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoinc_lock_mode) to `0` (a.k.a “traditional” lock mode) If you'd like to avoid gaps in your auto-increment columns. It may incur a performance penalty, though, as this mode has the effect of holding a table lock until the `INSERT` completes.

From the docs on [InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT Lock Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-modes):

> **`innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0`** (“traditional” lock mode)
>
> The traditional lock mode provides the same behavior that existed
>   before the `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` configuration parameter was
>   introduced in MySQL 5.1. The traditional lock mode option is provided
>   for backward compatibility, performance testing, and working around
>   issues with “mixed-mode inserts”, due to possible differences in
>   semantics.
>
> In this lock mode, all “INSERT-like” statements obtain a special
>   table-level `AUTO-INC` lock for inserts into tables with `AUTO_INCREMENT`
>   columns. This lock is normally held to the end of the statement (not
>   to the end of the transaction) to ensure that auto-increment values
>   are assigned in a predictable and repeatable order for a given
>   sequence of `INSERT` statements, and to ensure that auto-increment
>   values assigned by any given statement are consecutive.

Comment: Big thanks for giving the answer but pointing out the downsides as well.

Answer (score 14):

I believe this is a configurable setting in InnoDB. See: [AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html)

You'd want to go with

```
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0
```

Comment: Thank you, correct answer but I accepted the earlier correct.

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter care to explain their objection?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO `tablename` (id, rowname) SELECT '1', 'abc' FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM `tablename` WHERE `rowname`='abc');
```

or short (because the id field has an increment in the table )

```
INSERT INTO `tablename` (rowname) SELECT 'abc' FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM `tablename` WHERE `rowname`='abc');
```

The solution may look cumbersome, but it works as the author needs.

Comment: thanks [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173)

Answer (score 0):

I think this behaviour is reasonable. The auto-increment should not be relied upon to give sequences that don't have gaps.

For example, a rolled back transaction still consumes IDs:

```
 INSERT INTO t (normalcol, uniquecol) VALUES 
   ('hello','uni1'),
   ('hello','uni2'),
   ('hello','uni1');
```

Generates a unique key violation obviously, and inserts no rows into the database (assuming transactional engine here). However, it may consume up to 3 auto-inc values without inserting anything.

Comment: If you want to capture new unique occurrences in data stream of thousands of mostly repeating records per second, you may quickly run out of keys. When I expect 100 unique records at most, out of a trillion (INSERT IGNORE resulting in IGNORE great most of the time), I shouldn't need to allocate int(13) for key, but int(3).

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if it's expected, though I would recommend switching to:

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Comment: This increments the `auto_increment` value as well.

Comment: This has different semantics than INSERT IGNORE. They're not interchangeable

Comment: This would also result in gaps. The only real solution if you really need this is to set innodb_autoinc_lock_mode to 0.