# MySQL INSERT INTO WHERE NOT EXIST

Tags: mysql, sql

I will like to insert into same table if the ip_address for the product_id wasn't exist but preferably not to create two separate query. How can I achieve it?

Below will be the sample table:

```
id | product_id | ip_address |
------------------------------
a    11112        8.8.8.8
b    11234        9.9.9.9
```

and my code is something like this but it doesn't work.

```
INSERT INTO `'._DB_PREFIX_.'views` 
(SELECT '.$id_product.',"'.$ip_addr.'"
FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'views` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM
`'._DB_PREFIX_.'views` v WHERE v.id_product ='.$id_product.' AND
t.ip_address ="'.$ip_addr.'"
))'
```

Comment: Can you show us your current query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can either use `INSERT IGNORE` or `REPLACE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Each requires you to have a unique constraint on product_id, ip_address

**INSERT IGNORE**

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO products VALUES (null, 111, '8.8.8.8')
```

will ignore the insert, if entry already exists.

**REPLACE**

```
REPLACE INTO products VALUES (null, 111, '8.8.8.8')
```

will perform a delete plus a new insert.

**INSERT ... UPDATE**

```
INSERT INTO products VALUES (null, 111, '8.8.8.8')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE products SET last_modified = NOW()
```

Will try to insert and if that fails update the existing record.

In your case I think you should be fine with `INSERT IGNORE`, however If you want to change other values if the record already exists, `INSERT ... UPDATE ...` should work well.

I generally would not recommend to use `REPLACE` unless you really want a `DELETE FROM table WHERE ...` plus `INSERT INTO TABLE ...`

**Update**

This requires (for this example) a unique index for the combination product, ip_address.
You can achive this with

```
ALTER TABLE products
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `UIDX_PRODUCT__IP_ADRESS`(product, ipaddress);
```

Comment: Hi there your answer was something that I'm looking at but is it possible that the ip_address repeat more than once but in a different product id. How can I do that?

Comment: You can have a unique index for the combination product/ip_address, this allows you to have an ip_address assigned to multiple products but ensures that you can't insert the same ip_address for a product twice. I added the statement to modify your table to my answer

Comment: Hi again, this was just perfect. One more thought, I was using INSERT IGNORE and when the same product_id and ip_address being insert it does ignore, but the id itself incremented by 1. Is that the normal behavior?

Comment: Seems to be a bug/or feature? in InnoDB. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655396/why-insert-ignore-increments-the-auto-increment-primary-key on how to avoid this. I wasn't aware about this. You also could make `product_id+ip_address` your primary key, and drop the Autoincrement column.

Comment: Thanks, for your guides and helps. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can test the solution in the **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb8b5e/3)**.

Below is the sample Insert statement.

```
insert into temp
(select 2,101,'2.2.2.2'
from dual
where not exists (select * from Temp t 
              where t.product_id = 101 and
                    t.ip_address = '2.2.2.2'));
```

Comment: No, this is wrong and dangerous. Here's why: **[SQL-Fiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fcc5/2)**

Comment: Change the 3rd line from `from Temp` to `from dual` and it will be ok.

Comment: Now Recheck I have modified

Comment: +1 (and your first query with `NOT EXISTS` is far better that `COUNT(*)=0` check)