# Why does table with unique key keep incrementing the ID field?

Tags: mysql

I have a very ordinary MySQL table with an ID field and a couple of varchars.  One of the varchars is set as a UNIQUE KEY.  The odd thing (to me) is that whenever I attempt an insert of a duplicate value in the UNIQUE field the insert is discarded (correctly) but the ID field is incremented by 1, as if the insert had been successful.  Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `urls` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `label` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`)
)
```

I only have 10 or 12 rows in the table, but the ID sequence is like: 1,2,3,5,12,15,30 etc because of the insert attempts.

Should I set up the unique constraint in a different way, or do I have to do a SELECT before each INSERT to check for duplicate values?

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655448/929437

Comment: why does the ID of the row even matter to you?

Comment: @NDM In this example not much, but it matters a little in other tables where we often reference the IDs and find it annoying to have to remember 7-digit numbers when there are only an handful of entries in the table.

Answer (score 1):

This is know bug in MySQL as reported in the below link
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-configurable

innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0

for more reference on this read the following link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html